# Pass array of NSManagedObjects to a new view

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out how to fetch a list of NSManagedObjects, and then passing them to another view.

Here's my fetch

```
+ (NSArray *)fetchListOfParentSectors;
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Sector"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent_id = -1"]];

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator: [[JobDataModel sharedDataModel] persistentStoreCoordinator]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
        exit(1);
    }

    return results;
}
```

If I put a loop in here to log sector.name here it works perfectly.

Now in my view controller I have this:

```
NSArray *objectArray = [FetchSectors fetchListOfParentSectors];
for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.count; i++) {
    Sector *sector = (Sector *)[objectArray objectAtIndex: i];
    NSLog(@"name = %@", sector.name);
}
NSLog(@"objects = %@", objectArray);
```

The log results for name return (null). I know the array isn't empty as there are the correct amount of objects returned, and the log shows a bunch of objects listed like this:

`"<Sector: 0xac91020> (entity: Sector; id: 0xac8e900 <x-coredata://19C94F15-0A5B-4A40-8E68-17FE6C4950F8/Sector/p4> ; data: <fault>)"`

There has to be something simple that i'm overlooking here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core data objects can only exist in a managed object context. You create a MOC locally in `fetchListOfParentSectors`, but (assuming that you compile with ARC) this MOC is automatically released at the end of the function. Therefore, when you access the object's attribute `section.name`,  the MOC does not exist anymore.

I would have expected some runtime exception for this situation, but actually the accessor for the attribute returns just `nil` (I have verified that with a small test program.)

It makes therefore no sense to use a local MOC in `fetchListOfParentSectors`. You should use a global MOC, or create one in the view controller, and pass that as parameter to your fetch function.

Comment: Thank you for a logical and succinct response. I have often wondered if global moc's were a good idea, and now I know.