# CoreData NSManagedObject Not Saving

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a pretty simple base of an app so far, two textfields where the user enters the first and last name of a person and then when they tap the save button the following code runs:

```
person = (Person *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

NSError *err;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&err])
    {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", err, [err userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }
```

So I have a `Person` object, I set the first and last name as the user types into the textfield and then insert the object when choosing save. However, after saving, the first and last name are showing as `(null)`. I have all my outlets and methods hooked up correctly all code is being ran to set and save the name/object.

However, if I do this in the master view:

```
Person *p = (Person *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

PersonDetailViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PersonDetail"];
    vc.managedObjectContext = fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext;
    vc.person = p;
```

And then save my object, the values are not `(null)`. I am trying to insert the new object after deciding to save, rather than creating it then deleting it if cancelling to have cleaner and more logical code.

Comment: Is it the same managedObjectContext in both cases? Or does the first case use a separate or child MOC?

Comment: The first case uses the same MOC. Its passed down from the master view controller just like in the second case. Only difference being I am inserting the object either before or after the MOC has been passed down.

Comment: It was just an idea, because it reminded me of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875749/pass-array-of-nsmanagedobjects-to-a-new-view where attributes became nil after the MOC has been released.

Comment: Interesting thing to note. Inserting the object in the detail view is fine and the MOC is fine as well. However, so long as any attributes, such as first and last name are set on the object after insertion. So inserting the object during viewDidLoad works, but inserting the object upon leaving the view doesn't work, leaving values `(null)`. Any more ideas anyone?

Comment: Extra info: My `Person` object is nil prior to insertion. Meaning any first or last name property I set, doesn't actually get stored. Then, after insertion, the `Person` object is made nil as it treats it as a fresh object. So how can I store my attributes in the `Person` object prior to insertion?

Comment: If `Person` is nil, how can you use it to set attributes? - I don't think that you can store attributes in an object that is not inserted in a MOC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my `Person` object was returning nil.

Solution:
Initialise a `Person` object with nil context so that it isn't inserted but not nil. This way I can make sure of its variables to store things such as first and last name, then insert is like below.

```
person = [[Person alloc] initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];

Person *p = (Person *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        p.firstName = person.firstName;
        p.lastName = person.lastName;
```

This helped me reach this:
[Is there a way to instantiate a NSManagedObject without inserting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868514/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-a-nsmanagedobject-without-inserting-it)